# Bayesian Neural Network in Keras: transforming simple ANN into BNN

Tags: neural-networks, python, keras, bayesian-network

I am starting to learn about Bayesian Neural Networks. As such, apologies if my question may be too simple.

As a first step in my learning curve, I would like to transform a traditional ANN to a BNN. The ANN is very simple: 3 hidden layers, fully connected, with activation function given by `tanh` except for the output layer which has linear activation function.

This network should represent a mapping between my observables (in input) and the (6) parameters of my model, in output. The input observables are one-dimensional functions, which can be regarded as time series of 2001 time components, if one considers the independent variable as time.

The ANN architecture is shown below. As I said, I would like to transform this network into a Bayesian one. Following the excellent tutorial [here](http://krasserm.github.io/2019/03/14/bayesian-neural-networks/) I would think that the main changes to implement to obtain a BNN are: the 'neg_log_lieklihood' and the 'DenseVariational' layers.

Would these be the only transformations needed?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Lambda, Reshape, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, UpSampling1D, Flatten, Dropout
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K
from keras import losses
from keras import optimizers
from keras import regularizers

# np.loadtxt training and testing data
X_train = #np.loadtxt ...
X_test = # np.loadtxt ...

y_train = # np.loadtxt ...
y_test = # np.loadtxt ...


# dimension of input (and label)
n_x = X_train.shape[1] # 2001
n_y = y_train.shape[1] # 6

Dense_1 = 1500
Dense_2 = 700
Dense_3 = 200


x = Input(shape=(n_x, ))
hidden = Dense(Dense_1, activation='tanh')(x)
hidden = Dense(Dense_2, activation='tanh')(hidden)
hidden = Dense(Dense_3, activation='tanh')(hidden)

output = Dense(n_y)(hidden)

net = Model(x, output)

epochs = 400

def recon_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.square(y_true - y_pred))


optim = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
net.compile(optimizer=optim, loss=recon_loss, metrics=[recon_loss])

net_hist = net.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data = (X_test, y_test))
```